# How can i Import ruby on rails application to another computer

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I'm trying to import ruby on rails project to my computer but am running into all sorts of problems with the database.

**Here's the situation:**

I have an *appname.tar.gz* that I got from another developer. I extract it and relocated it to my user directory to work with it.

- Next I run `bundle install` in the directory to install gem
  dependencies.
- Then I run `rake db:create` to create the database and
  load the schema and structure from the DB folder in the same directory. This is where I'm running into all sorts of issues. When I launch the app I get an error saying DB migration pending.

  - structure.sql is a MySQL dump 10.13
  - while the database.yml file had the adapter set to postgres: `adapter: postgres`. Is this normal?

Is this the best way to import an existing app into your environment?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This might be helpful for you: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-install-the-mysql-gem-and-how-do-i-set-it-as-the-default-database-for-rails

On other hand, you missed `rake db:migrate` command. The `rake db:create` command is not enough.

Comment: No, it's not normal for a MySQL-backed app to have `adapter: postgres` in its `database.yml`. At any rate, if you're copying the whole database, you don't want to run any `rake db:` commands; you just want to import the whole SQL dump, which should create all of the tables.

Comment: @JordanRunning How would i go about importing the whole SQL dump?

Comment: @CodeHat That's answered in the MySQL docs as well as several Stack Overflow questions. P.S. I misspoke earlier. You probably want to do `rake db:create`, but you don't want to do any *other* `rake db:` commands. Importing the dump from the other database should recreate the same structure that your migrations would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! Thank you all for your help! Really appreciated it.
Below are the steps that worked for me:

1. Copy the project to the new computer
2. Open terminal and change directory to the project
3. Run `bundle install` to install all the gem dependencies
4. Run `bundle update` to update installed gems
5. Start the Postgres server by running `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`
6. Run `createdb databasename` to create the database on the new computer. The database name has to match the database mentioned in the database.yml file in the config folder.
7. Run `rake db:schema:load` and that's it!

After following the above steps I was able to run `rails s` to check out the website.

Comment: fair enough. Sure you have to ensure your database is running. Sorry I didn't mention this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like you got a MySQL dump and the application is configured to use postgres. I am wonderning why this is but you can try using the mysql adapter in your `config/database.yml` file by setting something like

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: foobar_development
```

The interesting bit is `adapter: mysql2`.

I have taken this from a brand new rails application. You need mysql running for sure.

Hope this helps. If not you have to reach out to the other person to get some postgresql compatible dump.

Comment: Thanks for this info but when I solely just do this I get an error that database doesn't exist.

Comment: When switching the adapter you need to run rails db:create and rails db:migrate to get things up and running

Comment: when doing `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

Mackbook-UserName$ bin/rails db:migrate
== 20150413001904 AddMetaDataToProducts: migrating ============================
-- add_column(:products, :meta_tags, :text, {:array=>true, :default=>[]})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled: